How to Optimize SSRS Report with Multiple Subreports
I have an SSRS report that contain 5 additional sub reports within it. Each sub report runs for each row in the main report result set as it uses the row data as parameters.
Alone, each sub report stored procedure has been optimized and is very fast, however the main report takes about 5 minutes to fully render.
I've looked through the executionlog3 view in our reporting services db and the TimeDataRetrieval is consistently over 300000ms (5 minutes).
The sub report stored procedures are relatively simple and complete within 100ms.
The report RDL file groups only on the ID column of the main result set so that each page is a different ID.
Scoured the internet for possible answers but nothing incredibly useful came up.
I've also tried to optimize the procs even more but the result was the same.
What are some best practices to possibly speed up this report? It is timing out when our web application tries to launch the report.

I would suggest you make a copy of the report and strip out the subreports, test that and see if it's the main report that is causing the issue. Then test each subreport in isolation, using parameters that you main report is passing. I can't think why the data retrieval time would so high if each individual report runs OK. If this does not help, share the report design including the subreports and how the parameters are being passed. There is not enough to go on at the moment.
